# is there anyway to strip the words from a song

Tags: music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Karaoke Software?](https://superuser.com/questions/28310/karaoke-software)

if i have a mp3 or another song file.  is there anyway to remove and strip out the words and just keep the music?

Comment: not sure about , but have you tried Audacity ?

Comment: Dupe.  http://superuser.com/questions/28310/karaoke-software

Comment: The results will be less than stellar; just try to find an instrumental version, it's better this way.

Answer (score 1):

[You can try to use Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/faq?s=editing&i=remove-vocals). However, there is no way to do this with consistency and with high quality. The best thing you can do is try to find instrumental (or karaoke) versions of your songs to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: (using Audacity)

[Remove the lyrics from most sonfs](http://www.instructables.com/id/Remove-The-Lyrics-From-Most-Songs/)